# Edit field from ForeignKey in Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-modeladmin

```
class BoxItem(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

class Box(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=150)
    item = models.ForeignKey(BoxItem)
```

admin:

```
admin.site.register(BoxItem)
admin.site.register(Box)
```

How can I add possibility to edit `BoxItem.quantity` value in `Box` single object admin page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `admin.py`:

```
class BoxAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    box_item_quantity = forms.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ populate box_item_quantity initial value """
        super(BoxAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.initial['box_item_quantity'] = self.instance.item.quantity

    class Meta:
        model = Box


class BoxAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BoxAdminForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(BoxAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        obj.item.quantity = form.cleaned_data.get('box_item_quantity')
        obj.item.save()


admin.site.register(Box, BoxAdmin)
```

This works because your BoxItem field is required. Otherwise, there might be some more logic needed to handle cases when `Box` has no `BoxItem` associated.

---

I must say, even though it's not in the question:
This model schema looks very weird to me. One `BoxItem` instance can be associated with many `Box` instances. Changing the `quantity` in one `BoxItem` can affect other `Box` instances as well, because they can be associated with the same `BoxItem`.
(This has nothing to do with the admin, it's true no matter the way that change to `quantity` field happens.)